# ActionFilter - Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect

I'm using the following ActionFilter to check if a session variable has been lost, if so they are redirected to the 'select a warehouse code screen'... As far as the user is concerned it is working fine... however ELMAH is reporting an error (see below code) every time I redirect via the ActionFilter.

P.S. This ActionFilter attribute is then put on a base controller, which all other controllers inherit.

P.P.S. There is no other redirect going on... this action filter is firing before the action they tried to perform... I can't for the life of me work out why I keep getting this error.

```
public class HasWarehouseCodeExpired : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Controller controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;

        if (controller != null)
        {
            if (SessionHelper.WarehouseCode == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "logon", action = "displaywarehouseselection", area = string.Empty }));
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

The error:

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.
>      at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)
>      at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)

Answer (score 2):

Well I still don't know why the error is occurring, however I stopped the error by adding:

> filterContext.HttpContext.Server.ClearError();

Like so:

```
if (SessionHelper.WarehouseCode == null)
{
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "logon", action = "displaywarehouseselection", area = string.Empty }));
    filterContext.HttpContext.Server.ClearError();
}
```